# Extending ArrayList - Cannot instantiate the type String?

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to extend `ArrayList`. I wanted to extend it such that the child class can contain only `String`s and nothing else. Why am I getting an error in my code?

```
import java.util.*;

public class ExtendedStringArray<String> extends ArrayList<String>{

    public String getAString() {
        return new String("Test");  
    }

}
```

Comment: Just make it: `public class ExtendedStringArray extends ArrayList<String> {`

Comment: Yes, it also causes a warning in eclipse - The type parameter String is hiding the type String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the generic type in your class declaration, just in the `extends` clause:

```
public class ExtendedStringArray extends ArrayList<String> {

    public String getAString() {

        return new String("Test"); 

    }

}
```

What you are saying here is that `ExtendedStringArray` extends a specific type of `ArrayList`, the `ArrayList` parameterized with the `String` type. Since you aren't using any generic type parameters for your class's implementation you don't need the `<>` in your class declaration.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler thinks that you are declaring a generic type parameter named `String`, which ends up hidding the actual `String` class. You cannot instantiate type parameters, hence the error.
You instead want:

```
class ExtendedStringArray extends ArrayList<String> {
     ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using `String` either in your class declaration either in what it extends from. This means that String is literally used as a type variable and your code is indeed equivalent to

```
public class ExtendedStringArray<T> extends ArrayList<T>{

  public T getAString(){
    return new T("Test"); 
  }

}
```

But this is not correct, as you can't instantiate a object of a generic type `T`.

Use: `class StringArrayList extends ArrayList<String> { ..` so that you specify that you are specializing an `ArrayList<String>` and not declaring a generic class.